# Getting string events

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I have a indexed string event.

```
event productAdd(
        address indexed adder,
        uint256 indexed productId,
        string indexed ipfsHash,
        uint256 addingTime
    );
```

I am try to get that string. It returns bytes32 but i couldnt convert it to string.

```
 const ipfsHash =
    "0x9adbfe8fa801df67ed96f852ee7a5c5e07ce293d6ee0947d4b27ba87d4cca033";

     ethers.utils.parseBytes32String(ethers.utils.hexStripZeros(ipfsHash, 32))
```

This throws error Error: invalid bytes32 string - no null terminator

Answer (score 2):

You can't just convert it from bytes32 to string because that value you're looking at is a keccak hash of the original string

Read [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/142532/99976) to a question someone post.. he was trying to do the same as you so this question might be a duplicate

Comment: The solution i found for this i added a function to my contract with retrieve that string ,from a mapping by using that productId

Comment: I actually suggested that In the other response :3 however that guy also mentioned about "not indexing the value would not get the string hashed therefore it's possible to extract the exact string"